# C# - xNet - how to add proxy support

Tags: c#, web, proxy, xnet

I made a checker for some website, however, I need to add Proxy support:

```
using (var request = new HttpRequest())
{
       request.Proxy = new HttpProxyClient(ProxyRandom());
}

public static string ProxyRandom()
{
       Random rnd = new Random();
       return Proxies[rnd.Next(0, Proxies.Count)];
}
```

for some reason, it doesn't work... the program doesn't post any data when I try to use proxies

what is the right way to add proxy support when I use xNet library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what *XNet* is, however i looked at the [GitHub](https://github.com/X-rus/xNet)

As you can see from their example shown prominently on the page , you are trying to put the proxy in to the `HttpRequest` constructor which i assume is the *Host Name*, use `request.Proxy` property instead is my guess

```
using (var request = new HttpRequest("Site name"))
{
    request.UserAgent = Http.ChromeUserAgent();
    request.Proxy = Socks5ProxyClient.Parse("127.0.0.1:1080");
```

Comment: Thank you :), can you tell me what you do to send HTTP requests instead of xNet?